# AEM Touch UI: no components in side rail

Tags: java, aem, sightly

We're still using the Classic UI in our AEM instance but I'm trying to push everyone to start using the Touch UI. The problem is, I cannot seem to get ANY components to show up in the side rail. I have enabled every single component in design mode, and they show up just fine in the Classic UI sidekick, but my side rail shows absolutely nothing, not even out-of-the-box components. And I know I have Touch UI-enabled components available since, if I drag a component into a page from Classic UI and then switch to Touch UI, I'm able to edit that component no problem. I just can't drag-and-drop anything while in Touch UI.

Anyone have any ideas on this? I've restarted the server because I read about caching issues, etc, and that solved nothing.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Did you added the components into the **design mode of touch UI** for that particular page .?

Comment: Yes, I did. I added every single component in my instance, including out-of-the-box compoentns. Still, not a single component shows up in the Touch UI side bar.

Comment: Is there any error in the page load.? and is this behaviour same for Geometrixx website pages also.?

Comment: check if its working on geometrixx sites, if not its unlikely to have anything to do with your components and something funky is going on with your instance.

Comment: Yep; no dice. Even the Gemoetrixx sites have the same problem... I am getting no page load errors or anything in the error logs for that matter that suggest a problem.

Comment: @user3444873 No Errors in browser console .?. it it is the case i guess some thing went wrong with your AEM installation.

Comment: Does your component have a touch UI dialog (cq:dialog child node)?

Answer (score 2):

To enable the components into Touch UI below steps you can follow.

Example taken for http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en/men/coats/edmonton-winter.html page

1. Change the mode of the page to Design 
   [image: Design mode Touch UI]
2. Select the parsys by clicking on the "Drag Components here"
   [image]
3. Then click on the Configure for that parsys. which will open up parsys design dialog
   [image: Settings of parsys]

[image: Design dialog]

4. Choose components that you are looking for to add to page. (Here i have chosen Text -Sightly component for demo )

[image: Test Sightly]

5. Where the component will appear in Edit mode as shown below.

[image: Sightly added]

Comment: But I've done that. In step 4, I've literally selected every single component in our entire instance including out-of-the-box components. Still, nothing shows up in the Components field of the side rail.

Comment: @user3444873 I'm experimenting the same issue, Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Classic UI dialogs which use the following structure

```
primaryType - 'cq:Dialog'

xtype - 'Dialog'
```

Touch UI dialogs should have the following key/value pairs:

```
primaryType - 'unstructured'

resourceType - 'cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog'
```

Followed by your dialog structure. You will need the corresponding dialog construct to enable component usage in either Classic UI or Touch UI.

This [HelpX article](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/developing-components-classic.html) provides high level information concerning the differences between the two dialog types.